# Display language icon in Fluid template

Tags: typo3, fluid

I would like to display the assigned language for each record by showing the respective language icon.

I plan to do this in a Fluid template in a BE module using TYPO3 8 with already existing TYPO3 icons.

I can read the value of sys_language_uid from the records.

The icons are already supplied by TYPO3, as I can see in the list of "Website Language" on pid=0.

I've also found a ViewHelper to do this .

So, what I have to do is something like:

- From the value of sys_language_uid, read the correct code from sys_language.language_isocode (e.g. 'en', 'es')
- Get the correct name for the icon from the isocode
- Display the icon with the ` ViewHelper

Is there a ViewHelper that already does this? Do I have to write it from scratch? What is an efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem here is that there are no icons for languages. Please do not confuse languages with countries where usually flags are used as icons.

Instead you should display the language in its language, so e.g. *Deutsch* for German.

This can be achieved if you load the `sys_language` record referred to by the language field in the record (usually `sys_language_uid`). There are quite a few ways to deal with this and since you already use Fluid you could try to get started with the [`<v:resource.record/>` viewhelper](https://fluidtypo3.org/viewhelpers/vhs/master/Resource/RecordViewHelper.html) from the *vhs* TYPO3 extension:

```
<v:resource.record
    table="sys_language"
    field="title"
    uid="{data.sys_language_uid}"
    as="languageTitle">
    {languageTitle}
</v:resource.record>
```

To have this applied to every record, you could copy and [customize the `Default.html` layout of Fluid StyledContent](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/fluid_styled_content/8.7/Configuration/OverridingFluidTemplates/) and output the language of the processed record there.

Comment: To use the resource.record ViewHelper, you need the additional extension "vhs".

Answer (score 1):

Since TYPO3 9:

If you already resolved the icons in your code, you can use the core icon ViewHelpers, e.g.

```
DE: <core:icon identifier="flags-de"/>
EN: <core:icon identifier="flags-en-us-gb"/>
```

You can see how the core does it to create the icons in the [PageLayoutView.php](https://github.com/TYPO3/TYPO3.CMS/blob/master/typo3/sysext/backend/Classes/View/PageLayoutView.php#L1969) using `renderLanguageFlag()` in `SiteLanguage`. (The languageFlag is what you can pass to the `core:icon` ViewHelper).

Important: This is code for the backend.

```php
$icon = $this->renderLanguageFlag($this->siteLanguages[(int)$row['sys_language_uid']]);

protected function renderLanguageFlag(SiteLanguage $language)
{
    $title = htmlspecialchars($language->getTitle());
    if ($language->getFlagIdentifier()) {
        // instead of this, you can getFlagIdentifier() and pass to Fluid
        $icon = $this->iconFactory->getIcon(
            $language->getFlagIdentifier(),
            Icon::SIZE_SMALL
        )->render();
        return '<span title="' . $title . '">' . $icon . '</span>&nbsp;' . $title;
   }
   return $title;
}

protected function resolveSiteLanguages(int $pageId)
{
    $site = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(SiteMatcher::class)->matchByPageId($pageId);
    $this->siteLanguages = $site->getAvailableLanguages($this->getBackendUser(), true, $pageId);
}
```

---

You could also create ViewHelpers for this, but I assume it would be more efficient to do this once in the controller (in case you are using the flags several times in the view).

Answer (score 0):

**Use the ICON API** (no VHS extension needed)

https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/8.7/ApiOverview/Icon/

Your controller could fetch the isocode from :

```
$this->TCP=GeneralUtility::makeInstance(TranslationConfigurationProvider::class);
$this->languages = $this->TCP->getSystemLanguages();
$this->view->assign('languages', $this->languages);
```

In FLUID you can get the icon like this:

```
{namespace core = TYPO3\CMS\Core\ViewHelpers}

<f:for each="{languages}" as="language" iteration="i">
    <core:icon identifier="flags-{language.flag}" size="small" />
</f:for>
```

where {language.flag} is your preferred lowercase isocode.

The core:icon attribue »overlay« – not used in this case – can stick icons together.

Look for the identifier names here: https://typo3.github.io/TYPO3.Icons/

For language flags you'll have to prefix the lowercase isocode with: "flags-"